# Codeigniter how to use credit card helper

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter

I have found a credit card validator. However, I am unsure of how to use it with callbacks. The function I want to use requires 4 inputs. However I can only pass one through the form validation now. Hope someone can help me with this.

Controller

```
public function next(){
        $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<p class="error">', '</p>');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('inputcardtype','Select Card Type','required|callback_check_default');
        $this->form_validation->set_message('check_default', 'Please select the month of expiration');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('inputcardnumber', 'Card Number', 'trim|required|xss_clean|callback_cardnumber_validation');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('inputexpirationdatemonth','Select Month','required|callback_check_default');
        $this->form_validation->set_message('check_default', 'Please select the month of expiration');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('inputexpirationdateyear','Select Year','required|callback_check_default');
        $this->form_validation->set_message('check_default', 'Please select the year of expiration');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('inputnameoncard', 'Name on Card', 'trim|required|xss_clean');

        $inputcardnumber = $this->input->post('inputcardnumber');
        $inputcardtype = $this->input->post('inputcardtype');
        if($this->form_validation->run()==false){
            $this->index();
        }else{

        }

    }

    function cardnumber_validation($string = NULL) {
         $this->load->helper('creditcardvalidation'); 

         if(checkCreditCard ($string, $cardtype, $ccerror, $ccerrortext)) {
            return TRUE;
        } 
        else{
            $this->form_validation->set_message("cardnumber_validation", 'The %s is not valid.');
            return FALSE;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The callbacks need to be named after a function.

If you have:

```
callback_check_default
```

You need to have a function called:

```
    function check_default() {
     //Your validation here
  }
```

Does that answer your question?

Comment: Sorry! I didn't specify! I want a callback for cardnumber_validation